# An early transit through US using using J1 and J2 visa during the 30 day grace period bfore the starting of the program

Tags: indian-citizens, j1-visas

I and my wife have J1 and J2 visas, respectively, and my DS-2019 program starts from the 1st July 2019.

Now, I have to travel to Canada on the 25th of June and my flight has a transit through Philadelphia.

Can I transit through the US to Canada using these J1 and J2 visas (which are valid from 1st July) on the 26th June 2019 (which falls within the 30 day grace period before the starting of the program)?

Comment: US visas do not have a "valid from" date; they are valid from the moment of issue.  Do you mean that the DS-2019 program period begins on that date, or that the 30-day grace period begins on that date?  Or is that date significant for some other reason?

Comment: My DS 2019 program starts from 1st July. However, I am expecting to get my visa stamped by first week of June. If we get out J1 and J2 visa by first week of June, can we use this visa to transit through US to Canada on June 25.

Comment: So the question really is whether you can use your J visas for a transit to Canada during the 30-day grace period that precedes the start of your program.  I suspect that the answer is *yes,* but I do not know.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you please suggest from where I can get confirmation on this?

Comment: @phoog Logically why not? J students/scholars are allowed to enter and leave the USA on their valid visas as many times as they want. As you pointed out his plans fall within the 30 day grace period so his _transit_ can just be viewed as coming to the USA and going back home before returning to actually start the program. I don’t think one will find explicitly a memo allowing it.

Comment: @user 56513 Thanks so much. Could you please suggest from where I can get a confirmation on this?

Comment: You can confirm from the consular officer at your J1 visa interview. What I would suggest you do is send an email to the consulate so they/he replies and you have a printed copy of the reply. That’s better evidence.

Comment: @user56513 "logically why not": because transit is not listed in the statutory requirements at [8 USC 1101(a)(15)(J)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1101#a_15_J).  Also Canada may not be (and I suspect is not in fact) "home," though I doubt that makes a difference.  I agree that this could be (and should be) viewed as arrival in the US during the grace period followed by a short trip to Canada during the grace period, but as you know there's always a possibility that the immigration inspector will not see it that way.

Comment: @phoog Fair point. I am assuming he already has a Canadian visa. I hope that’s the case.

Comment: user 56513 4 , yes I have a Canada visa.